# Issues installing Git under Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, git, osx-mavericks

I've just completed a fresh install of Mavericks. Then I went to [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/) and downloaded the Mac installer and installed Git from that.

Now whenever I go into the terminal and type `git` I get this:

```
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', 
requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line 
developer tools.
```

I also this dialog:

[image]

The git installer installed git into `/usr/local/git/bin` and I've added this to my `PATH` but still no dice.

What am I doing wrong here? I don't want to install xcode just so I can use git.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just download the [original git package](http://git-scm.com/download/mac). The installer will install git under `/usr/local/git` (you need to deactivate security options to run the installer).

There is a preinstalled git wrapper in `/usr/bin` used by Xcode which does not work without installing Xcode. You need to run `/usr/local/git/bin/git` explicit or change the PATH variable to contain `/usr/local/git/bin` before `/usr/bin`!

Create/edit your `~/.profile` with the following:

```
PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove that wrapper from xcode?

Comment: @JanHančič: Yes, `sudo rm /usr/bin/git`, but not recommended!

Comment: And for the record, I've done everything you said (as mentioned in OP). But I don't seem to know how to put my custom path before the existing ones. But I'd still prefer if I could just get rid of the (to me) useless wrapper ...

Comment: @JanHančič: Yes `/etc/profile` uses path_helper (try `man path_helper` to get an idea)

Comment: Weird, I've defined the path as per your edit and it's still at the end (and I have restarted all my terminal apps).

Comment: Yes, but should be at start and end, don't worry about the duplicate!

Comment: Try it with ~/.profile instead and relaunch terminal app

Comment: This works now yes. I guess my .bashrc doesn't get picked up somehow. Thanks!

Comment: For me worked the above but in ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Installing Xcode to use git, how ridiculous this Apple idea is :(

Comment: The solution worked only in `~/.bash_profile` and after reloading the bash_profile using `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) add:

```
/usr/local/git/bin
```

As the first line to `/etc/paths` and remove `/etc/paths.d/git` file to avoid duplication. This will affect all users.

Answer (score -1):

Just set an alias so when you call the git command it calls the right one instead of the wrapper...

```
alias git="/usr/local/git/bin/git" 

Mac-mini:/$ git -version
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.

Mac-mini:/$ alias git="/usr/local/git/bin/git"

Mac-mini:/$ git -version
Unknown option: -version
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```